# Other than inheritance , in real time web development do other OO features have any major role?

Tags: java, php, oop

In web development we use java .net or php5 .
All are OO. and have all the OO features.

But in real time websites do these OO features play any major role other than inheritance.?

Can anybody list some with real time examples.

In application development there may be a vast use of OO.
But in case of websites, does OO playing a major role?
How?

Comment: Why are you focussing on real-time websites?

Comment: @DJClayworth I think the OP means "in reality".  Is that correct @zod?

Comment: @DJ & Chris , i am a PHP developer, now every one is talking about OOP, am just trying to know what all areas of website development i can use this OOP. I am mainly seeing the inheritance and reusability everywhere. Other features are unknown to me where to implement :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back in 1995 the book [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) managed to produce this phenomenal insight on page 20:

> Favor object composition over class inheritance

Since then, proper object-orientation has been about that instead of inheritance. Particularly, the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles describe a set of principles for object-orientation that are applicable for any code base where **maintainability** is important. Polymorphism is important, but **inheritance is irrelevant**.

That applies to web applications as well as any other type of application.

Answer (score 3):

I make heavy use of encapsulation and polymorphism.  Specifically I use the Strategy Pattern  (among others) pretty heavily to compartmentalize a great deal of my functionality.  When combined with dependency injection, it makes it really easy for me to separate functionality of say, my persistence layer, from my business logic or presentation layer.

For instance, it's trivial to swap out a hibernate implementation with a JDBC implementation, etc.  Actually, recently, I just switched from an e-mail service that operates synchronously with the web request to one that uses a message queue to asynchronously send mail.  All I had to do once I'd implemented the new layer was change which class was injected into my beans that use it.

**Edit:** To address your comment, @zod, I don't use it so with with regards to the pages that are executed although that does happen from time to time (for instance, I have different classes for HTML email and plain text email depending on what the user has requested) but I primarily make use of the OO principals in the configuration of the application.  Does that make sense?

Comment: as you said you use encaps & poly , so did you mean that , you had some functions which will be called from different pages  and will perform different functionality based on from where and how it is called . Is my understanding correct. i just want to understand as a layman not much technical :-)

Answer (score 0):

As a start, the main principles of OO come in handy.Take for example data encapsulation in an MVC pattern; The fact that you can have a User model that does all the user stuff means that everything that has to do with users is encapsulated in that one model. This makes it easier to add and modify features later on. The extensibility also comes in handy when you want to extend your program with the code other people have written. As long as you know the public interface of their classes, you can use them.

Answer (score 0):

TO give a simple example we as a company heavily use it for security. We have plugins for various frameworks that controls who tries to reach which class and method. In addition to that we can avoid user to reach that class and method without adding extra lines to class.

Other than that we are using them to clarify the code as well.

Beside all of those doing OOP is good way to create a big project with a big team.

Comment: code seperation , compartmentalization of view , data and controller  .so frameworks came into picture only because of OOP. good point :-)